# disable fully reload with any changes in Next js

Tags: next.js, refresh, reload

I am working with **Next.js**.  Suddenly I realized that hot reload is not working. Instead, **with any changes in the page elements**, **the page would be** **fully refreshed**, **not hot reload**.

Let say that there is a file in **pages** folder called **test.js**. The content of test.js is as follows:

```
    function test() {

      return <div>Test <div>;
    }

   export default test;
```

the above code simply, *output a simple **test** message* in the page when visiting a local url like this: http://localhost:3000/test .

**When I change the test text into something else** such as **test2**, **I expect that I should see the new change (test2) instantly in the page (hot reload)**, **but** unfortunately **the page fully reloads first**, and then I can see the new changes in the page (in this example, the new test2 text). This is bothers me so much to wait to see the changes by page refreshing, not by hot reload.

**How I can tell Nex.js,  not to fully reload the page with any change in page element,** **but instantly show them** on the page, as it is expected ??

The console log message is as follows:
[image: console message for full reload]

Comment: There is a console log also:
Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload when ./pages/test.js changed.

Comment: One answer is given in:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40184#issuecomment-1301942294

Answer (score -4):

in your next.config.js, add this code:

```
const nextConfig = {
 fastRefresh: false, } module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: Where is this documented? All I can find is a GitHub issue with a thousand folks asking for this feature and frustrated that it doesn't exist.